# Tensorflow 1.0 Seq2Seq Decoder function

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, regression, sequence-to-sequence

I'm trying to make a Seq2Seq Regression example for time-series analysis and I've used the Seq2Seq library as presented at the Dev Summit, which is currently the code on the Tensorflow GitHub branch r1.0.

I have difficulties understanding how the decoder function works for Seq2Seq, specifically for the "cell_output".

I understand that the num_decoder_symbols is the number of classes/words to decode at each time step. I have it working at a point where I can do training. However, I don't get why I can't just substitute the number of features (num_features) instead of num_decoder_symbols. Basically, I want to be able to run the decoder without teacher forcing, in other words pass the output of the previous time step as the input to the next time step.

```
 with ops.name_scope(name, "simple_decoder_fn_inference",
                    [time, cell_state, cell_input, cell_output,
                     context_state]):
  if cell_input is not None:
    raise ValueError("Expected cell_input to be None, but saw: %s" %
                     cell_input)
  if cell_output is None:
    # invariant that this is time == 0
    next_input_id = array_ops.ones([batch_size,], dtype=dtype) * (
        start_of_sequence_id)
    done = array_ops.zeros([batch_size,], dtype=dtypes.bool)
    cell_state = encoder_state
    cell_output = array_ops.zeros([num_decoder_symbols],
                                  dtype=dtypes.float32)
```

Here is a link to the original code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.0/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/decoder_fn.py

Why don't I need to pass batch_size for the cell output?

```
    cell_output = array_ops.zeros([batch_size, num_decoder_symbols],
                                  dtype=dtypes.float32)
```

When trying to use this code to create my own regressive Seq2Seq example, where instead of having an output of probabilities/classes, I have a real valued vector of dimension num_features, instead of an array of probability of classes. As I understood, I thought I could replace num_decoder_symbols with num_features, like below:

```
     def decoder_fn(time, cell_state, cell_input, cell_output, context_state):
    """ 
    Again same as in simple_decoder_fn_inference but for regression on sequences with a fixed length
    """
    with ops.name_scope(name, "simple_decoder_fn_inference", [time, cell_state, cell_input, cell_output, context_state]):
        if cell_input is not None:
            raise ValueError("Expected cell_input to be None, but saw: %s" % cell_input)
        if cell_output is None:
            # invariant that this is time == 0
            next_input = array_ops.ones([batch_size, num_features], dtype=dtype)
            done = array_ops.zeros([batch_size], dtype=dtypes.bool)
            cell_state = encoder_state
            cell_output = array_ops.zeros([num_features], dtype=dtypes.float32)
        else:
            cell_output = output_fn(cell_output)
            done = math_ops.equal(0,1) # hardcoded hack just to properly define done
        next_input = cell_output
        # if time > maxlen, return all true vector
        done = control_flow_ops.cond(math_ops.greater(time, maximum_length),
                                     lambda: array_ops.ones([batch_size,], dtype=dtypes.bool),
                                     lambda: done)
        return (done, cell_state, next_input, cell_output, context_state)
return decoder_fn
```

But, I get the following error:

```
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py", line 212, in dynamic_rnn_decoder
swap_memory=swap_memory, scope=scope)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 1036, in raw_rnn
swap_memory=swap_memory)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2605, in while_loop
result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2438, in BuildLoop
pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2388, in _BuildLoop
body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 980, in body
(next_output, cell_state) = cell(current_input, state)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 327, in __call__
input_size = inputs.get_shape().with_rank(2)[1]
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 635, in with_rank
raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (100,) must have rank 2
```

As a result, I passed in the batch_size like this in order to get a Shape of rank 2:

```
    cell_output = array_ops.zeros([batch_size, num_features],
                                  dtype=dtypes.float32)
```

But I get the following error, where Shape is of rank 3 and wants a rank 2 instead:

```
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py", line 212, in dynamic_rnn_decoder
swap_memory=swap_memory, scope=scope)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 1036, in raw_rnn
swap_memory=swap_memory)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2605, in while_loop
result = context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2438, in BuildLoop
pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2388, in _BuildLoop
body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 980, in body
(next_output, cell_state) = cell(current_input, state)
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn_cell_impl.py", line 327, in __call__
input_size = inputs.get_shape().with_rank(2)[1]
File "/opt/DL/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 635, in with_rank
raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape (10, 10, 100) must have rank 2
```